# Can a person picker be pre-populated with current user in SP calendar new event form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, default-value, person

I have created a team calendar in SharePoint 2010.  I am using the standard New Event and Edit Event forms for user input.  To save time for the users and prevent input errors I am using a concatenation with the Created By field to Title the events.  My problem is when an item within a series is edited, a new event and new ID is created.  This is a problem when our office admins need to edit an item in another user's series. The Title is in the name of the Created By.  My thought is to add a person/group picker to the New and Edit event forms, and add some logic to my workflow to allow an editor to select the original creator of the series to solve the Title naming issues.  To continue on the path of saving time for my users and prevent errors I want to pre-populate the person/group picker with the current user's display name.  I have found some articles on possibly using javascript but not sure how that would be implemented.  Another thought is to ask, can setting the default value of the picker be done in SharePoint Designer?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Rather than use a people-picker to select the original creator and provide the input to save the Title as the original Created By, I added a new text column and field to the editform.aspx.  I added the logic to my WF to set the new field to equal the Created By name.  Then when editing if the new field is empty, Title equals Created By, and if the new field equals the Created By, set the Title to equal the new field.